# Для чего в PostgreSQL в политике доступа (pga_hba.conf) есть метод trust?

Tags: postgresql, безопасность

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если есть доступ к файлу pga_hba.conf, то при желании войти под определенным именем пользователя можно поставив в указанном файле для этого пользователя метод TRUST ? И этот пользователь даже не узнает, что под его именем входили ? Для чего сделали такую возможность подмены в PostgreSQL, а для например MS SQL так не сделали ? В MS SQL если администратор хочет подменить собой пользователя, то он должен отнять возможность аутентификации у пользователя (т.е. сменить пароль). И пользователь об этом узнает.

Answer (score 0):

Если указан метод `TRUST` - то тому, кто может подключиться к серверу с БД, можно войти под любым пользователем без введения пароля и без какой-либо другой аутентификации.

Подробнее в документации: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/auth-methods#AUTH-TRUST

Comment: Так вопрос и был "ЗАЧЕМ" сделали такую возможность одному пользователю "ПРИТВОРИТЬСЯ" другим пользователем ?  Если админ изменяет пароль у пользователя и сам заходит под ним, то он не "притворяется" другим, а отнимает у пользователя возможность пройти аутентификацию. И это нормально. А просто притвориться - это не нормально.  Для безопасности существование этого TRUST очень плохо.